# AJAX threading - how to wait for it to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm wondering how can I make my script wait for AJAX to complete:

```
function urlExists(testUrl){
    var ajaxurl = 'some AJAX URL';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
                "action": "somefunction",
                "content": testUrl
            },
        global: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('ajax successs');
            return true;
        },
        error: function(){
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

/* The AJAX function returns TRUE or FALSE 100% alright. */
/* The interesting part begins below. */

if(urlExists(src)){
    alert('test');
}else{ 
    alert('test2');
}
```

When AJAX returns TRUE (or FALSE) the `if(urlExists(src))` always says `test2`... I bet it's because it's not waiting for AJAX to complete? But what does this do then? Why it's like that? I get `test2` and soon after that `ajax successs`. I need it to display `test` message. Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Test for existence of the url in the `success` function. AJAX, by definition, is asynchronous, so js is not going to wait for the result. Instead, use your `success` callback.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. The success handler is called later on...

Comment: You can also make any ajax requests asynchronous by passing the async: false in the config of your request. If you don't want to do that, do what @JonathanM suggests: execute the code you want to wait for the ajax request's outcome in the success callback.

Comment: Please don't use `async:false`. There is always a better way to do it. Take it from someone who bears the scars of having done it the wrong way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because AJAX is aynchronous, meaning the AJAX call is made and execution continues without waiting for the response to come back. Thats why your `urlExists`() executes before the response comes. To call it after the response has arrived call in the success handler like so:

```
function urlExists(testUrl){
    var ajaxurl = 'some AJAX URL';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
                "action": "somefunction",
                "content": testUrl
            },
        global: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('ajax successs');
            if(urlExists(src)){
                 alert('test');
             }else{ 
                 alert('test2');
                  }
            return true;
        },
        error: function(){
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

/* The AJAX function returns TRUE or FALSE 100% alright. */
/* The interesting part begins below. */
```

Answer (score 2):

> The AJAX function returns TRUE or FALSE 100% alright.

No. It always returns `false`, as stated in its last line.

> how to wait for it to complete?

You can't "wait" in terms of "sleeping", as it is an *asynchronsous* task. You will need to use a callback. With jQuery's Deferreds, it looks like this:

```
function urlExists(testUrl){
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'some AJAX URL',
        data: {
                "action": "somefunction",
                "content": testUrl
            },
        global: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('ajax successs');
        }
    });
}
urlExists(src).done(function(){
    alert('test');
}).fail(function(){ 
    alert('test2');
}); // returns the promise immediately, but will alert later on
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! For some reason `urlExists(src)` returns JS error - function is not defined. I'm using that in the same scope so I'm not sure what happens. However, I made it work in `success` callback successfully :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your request asynchronous, however i do not suggest it. It will result in a poor user experience any time the network or server doesn't respond quickly.

```
function urlExists(testUrl){
    var result;
    var ajaxurl = 'some AJAX URL';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        async: false, // BAD
        data: {
                "action": "somefunction",
                "content": testUrl
            },
        global: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('ajax successs');
            result = true;
        },
        error: function(){
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

if(urlExists(src)){
    alert('test');
}else{ 
    alert('test2');
}
```

The recommended way is to instead use deferred objects or callbacks. Below is an example using deferreds.

```
function urlExists(testUrl){
    var ajaxurl = 'some AJAX URL';
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
                "action": "somefunction",
                "content": testUrl
            },
        global: false
    });

}

urlExists(src).done(function(){
    alert('test');
}).fail(function(){
    alert('test2');
});
```

**also note though if you are testing for the existence of a cross-domain url, this will always fail.**

Comment: Second example still shows `async:false`. Need to edit it and remove.